# Почему появляется баг в слайдере при добавлении responsive?

Tags: slick.js, bootstrap4

Скажите пожалуйста почему появляется баг в слайдере при добавлении responsive? Если адаптацию в слайдере убрать, то все работает.
Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://dantist.takercorporation.com/clinic.html), слайдер размещен в начале страницы в аккордеоне.
Код прикладываю:

```
$('.works-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    fade: false,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    swipe: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 576,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        }
    ]
});

$('.collapse__content').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.works-slider').slick('reinit');
});
```

Comment: Какой баг появляется?

Comment: @E_K Такой:
http://joxi.ru/RmzLy8GiYz6eXA  
http://joxi.ru/v29kY9BUZnEy3r

Comment: Добавьте ваш `html` код

Comment: @E_K html код можно увидеть перейдя по ссылке.

Comment: Нужен чистый кусок кода, без slick класов и оберток.
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Причину нашел. При открытии и закрытии аккордеона дублируется код слайдера. Остается понять как это исправить.

Comment: html код слайдера в оригинале показать не могу, так как уже изменил структуру.

Comment: Убрать `reinit` при `show.bs.collpase`?